# SQL Syntax Error/Cannot Add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

When I try to insert the values into the table "medlimir" I get this error:

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`2508962989_funi`.`medlimir`, CONSTRAINT `fk_medlimir_poststod1` FOREIGN KEY (`poststod`) REFERENCES `poststod` (`postnumer`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)"

If I try to insert the values one by one, I get the following:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

I have no idea why this happens, I've looked at some similar questions but I haven't seen one that applies to this. Here's my code;

```
INSERT INTO medlimir VALUES
('ChildID1', 'Childname1', 'ChildHome1', 'Phone', 'Sport', 'M', '61907792409', 220),
('ChildID2', 'Childname2', 'Childhome2', 'Phone', 'Kúla', 'M', '15776113692', 220),
('ChildID3', 'Childname3', 'CHildHome3', 'Phone', 'Þríþraut', 'M', '94364592306', 111),
('ChildID4', 'Childname4', 'ChildHome4', 'Phone', 'Hlaup', 'M', '30848878228', 111),
('1410908008', 'Tsunayoshi Sawada', 'Namimori High', '6966873', 'Hlaup', 'M', '28028131468', 220),
('2608903265', 'Ryohei Sasagawa', 'Namimori Box', '4476920', 'Box', 'M', '91010668790', 220),
('0909906666', 'Gokudera Hayato', 'Namimori High', '1024632', 'Spjót', 'M', '63229758735', 220),
('2404903568', 'Takeshi Yamamoto', 'Namimori High', '', 'Kúla', 'M', '62750060985', 220),
('2501106575', 'Giotto Primo', 'Vongola Mansion', '', 'Langst.', 'M', '37282894310', 600),
('0512904873', 'Chrome Dokuro', 'Kokuyo', '', 'gólfleikf.', 'F', '17904297752', 111),
('0505903157', 'Hibari Kyoya', 'Kondo', '8018296', 'Tvíslá', 'M', '64388759435', 000),
('2805991337', 'Lambo', 'Namimori', '', 'Þríþraut', 'M', '81540318862', 600),
('1309035730', 'Reborn', 'Vongola Mansion', '6118960', 'Spjót', 'M', '45849294908',  600),
('0707031683', 'Colonnello', 'Vongola Mansion', '8663306', 'Kringla', 'M',     '35282586046', 111),
('20020342489', 'Lal Mirch', 'Vongola Mansion', '947033', 'Kringla', 'F', '71126656838', 111);
```

The first 4 values were real, so I changed them a bit, rest is fake information. Any idea as to what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing symbol in the fifth line.
Instead of

```
('ChildID4', 'Childname4, 'ChildHome4', 'Phone', ...
```

it should be

```
('ChildID4', 'Childname4', 'ChildHome4', 'Phone', ...
                        ^
                        |____ this is the missing symbol
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a mistake on my part during the censoring pre-post. It's not in the real code. Any other ideas?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. The first error suggests that you are trying to insert a record that contains a value (for the column `poststod`) which should already be into another table (`poststod.postnumer`) but probably it isn't so. However, when you try to insert the records one by one, you get another error which clearly states that you wrote an incorrect SQL statements. 
Without the structure of the tables involved in your queries and without the real queries, it's very difficult to help you. Anyway, I really suspect that you made mistakes in writing SQL statements.